# In my laravel with react project the laravel Validator for image is returning validation errors even when the inputs are right

Tags: reactjs, laravel

This is my postman response even when valid inputs are inserted with.jpg,png,and jpeg files

```
"status": 422,
    "errors": {
        "image_name": [
            "The image name must be an image.",
            "The image name must be a file of type: jpeg, png, jpg."
        ]
    }
```

this is my react app swal() gives image is mandatory after that I get the same error as the postman. There is no error from my console and postman

```
import axios from 'axios';
import React, { Profiler, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import swal from 'sweetalert';
import Navbar from '../../../layouts/frontend/Navbar';

function Image(){
    
    const [picture, setPicture] = useState([]);
    const [errorlist, setError] = useState([]);

    const handleImage = (e) => {
        setPicture({image : e.target.file});

    }

    const submitImage = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('image',picture.image);

        axios.get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie').then(response => {

        axios.post('/api/image',formData).then(res=>{
            if(res.data.status === 200)
            {
               swal("Success",res.data.message,"Success");
               setError([]);

            }
            else if(res.data.status === 422)
            {
                swal("image is mandatory","","error");
                setError(res.data.errors);
            }
        });
    });
    }
    return(
        <div>
            <Navbar/>
            <div className="container py-5">
                <div className="row justify-content-center">
                    <div className="col-md-6">
                        <div className="card">
                            <div className="card-header">
                                <h4>Image</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div className="card-body ">
                                <form onSubmit={submitImage} encType="mutipart/form-data">
                                <input type="file" name="image" onChange={handleImage} value={picture.image}/>
                                <small className="text-danger">{errorlist.image}</small>
                                <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary px-4 mt-2">Submit</button>
                            </form>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Image;
```

this is my laravel controller validator gives the same result whether the input is valid or not

```
public function image(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),[
            'image' =>'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg|max:2048',
        ]);

        if($validator->fails())
        {
            return response()->json([
                'status' => 422,
                'errors' => $validator->messages(),
            ]);
        }
        else
        {
            $image = new Image;
             if($request->hasFile('image'))
             {
                 $file = $request->file('image');
                 $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
                 $filename = time().'.'.$extension;
                 $file->move('uploads/profileImage/',$filename);
                 $image->image_name = 'uploads/profileImage'.$filename;
                 return response()->json([
                    'status' => 200,
                    'message' => 'image added successfully',
                ]);
             }
             
           
        }
         
    }
```

Comment: I think you have some mix up somewhere, becasue your error response says ```image_name``` and the field is ```image```

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work the same error saying image name...but when I remove the validations required|... it works..but I needed the validations that's why..

Comment: "status": 422,
    "errors": {
        "image_name": [
            "The image name field is required."
        ]
    } this is the error that I got after changing it to image_name